# Receiving the Request from Form Stack

Tags: formstack

I have created a form using Form Stack and which is integrated with my actual application. But the problem is the Fromstack is not able to post the data to actual application. I am getting the below error

```
http://192.168.1.22:8080/mavenproject1/rest/api/formStackConvertor
There was an error submitting to Webhook http://192.168.1.22:8080/mavenproject1/rest/api/formStackConvertor. HTTP Status Code: 0. cURL Error: 28 - connect() timed out!. Total Runtime: 0 Name Resolution: 5.6E-5 second(s) Connection: 0 second(s) Redirect Time: 0 second(s) Redirect Count: 0 redirect(s) Pre-Transfer Time: 0 second(s) Start Transfer Time: 0 second(s) Remote time: -1 seconds(s)
```

I configured the Send Data to an External URL (WebHook) as

http://192.168.1.22:8080/mavenproject1/rest/api/formStackConvertor

Any Suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, My application is deployed in our local server (VPN) and not exposed to internet

So i exposed the application over the internet and configured the application url in the `formstack`

Comment: I am new in formstack and webhook. I want to receive the data of the form submitted on formstack in my C# application. I searched and searched a lot but didn't find any helpful solutions or examples. Can you please provide any sample code to receive data of form in my C# application.

Comment: @ajain formstack is the third party app which gives the output in form of JSON/XML , first write one connector/translator project in java or another tech ( we have exposed one rest api which we configured in formstack webhook). This connector will translate the json to our own format(we used velocity template http://velocity.apache.org/) and consume the output in the acutal application